# What tool to use to fast develope scalable web app module for simple PR-site

Tags: php, python, grails, frameworks

I have simple site written on PHP+mySQL (CMS created by 3rd party). It hosted on VPS, on CentOS+Apache+MySQL. I need to create personal cabinet module (client can create orders and view statistics of his orders). I want to create fully independent from existed CMS code module. One of the reasons - I want to use this module in other project in future.

Module must be lightweight for 1-st release, but should be easelly scaled in future with new functions. What rapid web developement tool to use (framework)? I also restricted now with current VPS hosting, but can install new components.

I think about Grails, but it can be too heavy for current hosting, it requires JAVA enviroment (or is it unnecessary fears?)
Then I read about python frameworks, but there dozens of them, what one to choose? And am I right, that python frameworks will require only installation of Python on VPS and application will be more lightweight then developed with Grails?

There are PHP frameworks, but I want to get experience in Grails or Python :) But maybe there are some objective reasons, why Grails and Python more preferable, or maybe not. Could someone share thoughts about that? Thanks.

Comment: This all comes down to personal preference, so doesn't seem like a valid question to me.

Comment: Don't forget that PHP is already a "framework" and templating engine. So you can template your framework while you're frameworking a template. Yo dawg...

Comment: Guys why do you down vote Artyoms question? That's not just personal preference - reread the question for requirements: It was written why to choose Grails OR Pyhton OVER PHP; it should be easily scalable/extendible. I guess there are tons of arguments why to choose any language over PHP?

Comment: Of course the Grails vs any Python framework part is no real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If low cost for hosting is not a major requirement I would not suggest PHP. As you wrote you want to re-use the component for future projects and easily extend it's functionality I would suggest to choose a framework which is based on an object oriented language. Of course you can do OO-like stuff with PHP but only upon a certain grade and it often feels more like a hack.

If you choose Grails or a Python framework is more a personal preference. Performance-wise it clearly depends on which Python framework you'd choose as you try to compare a framework (Grails) with a language (Python). For a Grails application your hoster should provide at least 256MB RAM. I can't speak of Python frameworks. And that the JVM is per se *slow* is a long lasting myth.